# Hyperlink to local file or folder in Hero web part - Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink

I have created a Hero web part in Sharepoint Online that links to an Excel file in a library. I need the file to open in the locally installed Excel application but it keeps opening in the browser version. I have changed the settings in the library itself to open files in the local application but when I click it from the link in the Hero web part, it still opens in the browser.

As a workaround I am now trying to add a hyperlink that points to the local excel file itself but the Hero web part will only allow me to add a link to an actual website. Does anyone know if there is any other way of getting it to open Excel in the local client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is OOB approach for your reference.

Set library to open document in client.

[image]

Copy generated OuterHtml link for your excel file.

[image]

Paste to content editor/script editor web part of your page.

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for the reply. I have tried to figure out how to get the OuterHtml to copy but an unsure how I would do this. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just click right key when you hover on the element.